# Guessing game adding a method

Tags: java, methods, jgrasp

I need to add a method to my guessing game that i made a while ago. The method should return the value they enter but should use a loop to require re-entry until one of those two values has been specified.
Also if the user inputs a word and not an int, it should ask for a number. I know that I will need to use a string instead of an int. I'm just having trouble figuring this out. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Random;

import java.util.Scanner;

class GuessNumber {

    static Random rand = new Random(); 
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    static int number; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        playGame();
    }

    public static void playGame() {
        number = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
        System.out.println("Guess the number between 1 and 100");
        while (true) {
            int guess = scan.nextInt();
            if (guess < number) {
                System.out.println("Higher!");
            } else if (guess > number) {
                System.out.println("Lower!");
            } else if (guess == number) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("do you wanna play again?[Y/N]");
                String val = scan2.next();
                if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                    playGame();
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ... And? Is there a question here?

Comment: @Qix That apparently is part of the guessing game it self...

Comment: If you know you're going to have to use a String instead of an int, start by rewriting your code to reflect what you (correctly) know you're going to need. Then use your Internet Search Fu to learn about String's parseInt() method. Take a few moments to read what you find and think about how you can use parseInt() to cast String input to a number which you can compare. Alternatively, look into String's compare() method to see whether one String is lexicographically higher, lower or the same as another String.

Comment: no like when it asks for a number if i put a word in there it crashes. I need to make it so the game keeps asking for a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a better way to do it but try something along the lines of:

```
String input = scan.next();
int guess;
try{
    guess = Integer.parseInt(input);
    //rest of the code inside while(true) loop
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("You need to enter a valid number.");
}
```

and then for the Y/N validation:

```
String val = "No";
Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
do{
    System.out.println("do you wanna play again?[Y/N]");
    val = scan2.next();
}
while(!val.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") && !val.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
if (val.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
   playGame();
   break;
} else {
   break;
}
```

Reasoning: You will get an error if they do not enter a valid number so you need to catch the error and let them know what is wrong. I like to get input as string and try to convert it to integers. As for the do/while section... Unless they enter Y or N it will keep asking them. Once out of the loop, if the input was "Y" it will call the playGame() again and then break after it finishes (basically whenever the user types n in the next game). If it wasn't "Y" then it had to be "N" and needs to break.

Let me know if this helps. I have the full code that will work but this should be easy enough for you to implement.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your static variables, put:

```
static int number, guess;
```

To declare both numbers at the same time. Then, inside the main loop, do the following:

```
while (true) {
    while (true) {
        try {
            guess = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Not a valid number!");
            continue;
        }
    }
    //Rest of your if's, else if's, etc
}
```

I've tested it, and it works for me.

If you need me to I can paste in all the code, but you should be able to just nest that second while loop inside the first, before the if statements, easily enough.